# How to store a location (CLLocationCoordinate2D) inside a class w/o leaking memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

I am creating a library which contains an API for setting the current location based off some value collected by the GPS. I want to store this location in my class and later, change the behavior of my library if it is set.

What I had in mind was:

```
@interface myLib
{
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationCoordinate2D *location;
}

@implementation myLib
{
@synthesize location = _location;

- (void)setLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)loc {
location = loc;
}

- (void)someFunc {
 if (location != nil) ...  
}

}
```

However, retain isn't a valid property for a CLLocationCoordinate2D object.

So, what is the proper way to save CLLocationCoordinate2D for later use w/o wasting memory?

Answer (score 13):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a non-object type.  It does not inherit from `NSObject` so it cannot be `retain`ed.  So declare your instance variable like so

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
```

With the property declaration like:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
```

And then your `setLocation:` method is simply:

```
- (void)setLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newLocation {
    location = newLocation;
    // other stuff
}
```

This `setLocation:` method is also optional since the synthesized property will assign for you.  But you seem to want to do some other stuff when a new location is assigned, so this should let you do that.

Comment: ah yes, good pt, forget it's not a NSObject - compiler should know this, i wonder if he's getting warnings and wonder what the compiler does here.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize will generate the getters and setters for you.

Therefore this is redundant
- (void)setLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)loc {
location = loc;
}

And technically wrong, because that's "assign" setter and not a "retain" setter.

This is where my guess the leak is happening

Comment: Well this is a simplified example, hte actual set call also does a quick math operation.

What would the matching @property string be?